# Unable to remove paired device in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

As I see it, bluetoothctl removes device, but it remains paired somewhere in settings and tries to connect again.

```
[bluetooth]# paired-devices
    Device 30:39:26:FF:15:43 SBH20
    Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB kimilky
[bluetooth]# untrust F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB
    Changing F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB untrust succeeded
[bluetooth]# remove F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB
    Device has been removed
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB Connected: no
    [DEL] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB kimilky
    [NEW] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB kimilky
[bluetooth]# paired-devices
    Device 30:39:26:FF:15:43 SBH20
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB Modalias: bluetooth:v0075p1200d1436
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB Paired: yes
[bluetooth]# paired-devices
    Device 30:39:26:FF:15:43 SBH20
    Device F0:6B:CA:16:8F:AB kimilky
```

Is there a way to remove it so that I could pair it as a new device?

Permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x   29 root root    4096 фев  5 18:40 /.
drwxr-xr-x    4 root root   12288 фев  5 18:39 /bin
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  192760 мар  1  2016 /bin/hciconfig
drwxr-xr-x  202 root root   12288 фев  5 18:44 /etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root    4096 апр 18  2016 /etc/bluetooth
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     397 май 19  2014 /etc/bluetooth/input.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    3874 сен 28  2015 /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     120 май 31  2011 /etc/bluetooth/network.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     258 июн 13  2012 /etc/bluetooth/proximity.conf
drwxr-xr-x    4 root root    4096 янв 18 15:57 /etc/dbus-1
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root    4096 янв 24 23:53 /etc/dbus-1/system.d
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1630 окт 20  2015 /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   12288 янв 24 23:53 /etc/init
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     997 сен 16  2015 /etc/init/bluetooth.conf
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root    4096 фев  5 18:40 /etc/init.d
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root    2968 сен 16  2015 /etc/init.d/bluetooth
drwxr-xr-x   29 root root    4096 янв 10 09:49 /lib
drwxr-xr-x    8 root root    4096 янв 24 23:53 /lib/systemd
drwxr-xr-x   29 root root   36864 янв 29 11:29 /lib/systemd/system
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     384 мар  1  2016 /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
drwxr-xr-x    4 root root    4096 янв 29 11:29 /lib/udev
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   14408 мар  1  2016 /lib/udev/hid2hci
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   12288 янв 29 11:29 /lib/udev/rules.d
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     113 мар  1  2016 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-bluetooth-hci-auto-poweron.rules
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1518 мар  1  2016 /lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules
drwxr-xr-x   15 root root    4096 июн 15  2016 /usr
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root  102400 фев  5 18:39 /usr/bin
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  192792 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/bccmd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   34888 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/bluemoon
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  137512 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/bluetoothctl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   26696 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/btattach
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  264280 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/btmgmt
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  589784 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/btmon
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  136760 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/ciptool
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  232160 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/gatttool
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  133016 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/hciattach
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  138776 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/hcitool
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   14408 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/hex2hcd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   94024 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/l2ping
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  106568 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/l2test
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   92424 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/obexctl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  140712 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/rctest
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  102904 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/rfcomm
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  205720 мар  1  2016 /usr/bin/sdptool
drwxr-xr-x  224 root root   36864 фев  5 18:39 /usr/lib
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root    4096 апр 18  2016 /usr/lib/bluetooth
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root 1149184 мар  1  2016 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root   92520 мар  1  2016 /usr/lib/bluetooth/mpris-proxy
drwxr-xr-x    4 root root   12288 фев  5 18:40 /usr/sbin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root      27 мар  1  2016 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -> ../lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
drwxr-xr-x  489 root root   20480 янв 22 00:51 /usr/share
drwxr-xr-x    6 root root    4096 янв 24 23:53 /usr/share/apport
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   45056 фев  5 18:39 /usr/share/apport/package-hooks
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1049 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_bluez.py
drwxr-xr-x    6 root root    4096 янв 18 15:57 /usr/share/dbus-1
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root    4096 янв 24 23:53 /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services
-rw-r--r--    1 root root      95 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.bluez.service
drwxr-xr-x 3422 root root  139264 фев  5 18:40 /usr/share/doc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root    4096 апр 18  2016 /usr/share/doc/bluez
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1680 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/doc/bluez/changelog.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    4356 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/doc/bluez/copyright
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    2689 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/doc/bluez/NEWS.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1656 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/doc/bluez/README.Debian.gz
drwxr-xr-x   96 root root    4096 окт  9 00:46 /usr/share/man
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root  135168 фев  5 18:39 /usr/share/man/man1
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1171 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/bccmd.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     526 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/bluemoon.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     349 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/bluetoothctl.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     458 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/btattach.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     445 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/btmon.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1093 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/ciptool.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     679 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/gatttool.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1577 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/hciattach.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1934 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/hciconfig.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1852 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/hcitool.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     408 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/hex2hcd.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     758 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/hid2hci.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     856 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/l2ping.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     795 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/l2test.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     437 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/mpris-proxy.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     672 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/rctest.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1477 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/rfcomm.1.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    1556 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man1/sdptool.1.gz
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   53248 фев  5 18:40 /usr/share/man/man8
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     880 мар  1  2016 /usr/share/man/man8/bluetoothd.8.gz
drwxr-xr-x   18 root root    4096 окт  8 23:34 /var
drwxr-xr-x  110 root root    4096 дек 22 21:27 /var/lib
drwxrwxrwx    3 root root    4096 мар 19  2016 /var/lib/bluetooth
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try the command:

```
bt-device --remove kimilky
```